# Show that $(M \otimes_R N) \otimes_R P \simeq M \otimes_R (N \otimes_R P)$.

Tags: modules, tensor-products

> Let $M,N$ and $P$ be $R$-modules. Then
>
> $$(M \otimes_R N) \otimes_ R P \simeq M \otimes_R (N \otimes_R P).$$

The proof of the above as given in the lecture note given by our instructor is as follows $:$

> The map $(M \otimes_R N) \times P \longrightarrow M \otimes_R (N \otimes_R P)$ given by
>
> $$(x \otimes y , z) \mapsto x \otimes (y \otimes z)$$
>
> is a well defined $R$-bilinear map on $(M \otimes_R N) \times P$, which can be extended to an $R$-bilinear map $(M \otimes_R N) \otimes_R P \longrightarrow M \otimes_R (N \otimes_R P)$ given by
>
> $$(x \otimes y) \otimes z \mapsto x \otimes (y \otimes z).$$
>
> This is an isomorphism with inverse given by $x \otimes (y \otimes z) \mapsto (x \otimes y) \otimes z$ defined similarly.

Now I am trying to prove the well-definedness of the first map i.e. the map $(M \otimes_R N) \times P \longrightarrow M \otimes_R (N \otimes_R P)$ defined by

$$(x \otimes y , z) \mapsto x \otimes (y \otimes z)$$

For this I take two elements $(x_1 \otimes y_1, z_1),  (x_2 \otimes y_2, z_2) \in (M \otimes_R N) \times P$ with $(x_1 \otimes y_1, z_1) = (x_2 \otimes y_2,  z_2)$. Then to show the well-definedness we must show that $x_1 \otimes (y_1 \otimes z_1) = x_2 \otimes (y_2 \otimes z_2)$. But I have failed to show that.

Would anybody please help me in this regard?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need $R$ commutative here.

To show your map is well-defined, fix $z\in P$. Then
$$(x,y)\mapsto x\otimes (y\otimes z)$$
is bilinear from $M\times N$ to $M\otimes(N\otimes P)$. Thus
it induces a linear map from $M\otimes N$ to $M\otimes(N\otimes P)$
with $x\otimes y\mapsto x\otimes(y\otimes z)$. So $(x\otimes y,z)
\mapsto x\otimes(y\otimes z)$ is well-defined from $(M\otimes N)\times P$
to $M\otimes(N\otimes P)$.

Of course the "right" way to prove this associativity is to prove that
both sides are universal objects representing trilinear
maps from $M\times N\times P$.

Comment: How can I show the well-definedness of the linear map you mentioned? I first take two elements $x_1 \otimes y_1$ and $x_2 \otimes y_2$ from the generating set of $M \otimes_R N$ with $x_1 \otimes y_1 = x_2 \otimes y_2$ then how do we show that $x_1 \otimes (y_1 \otimes z) =  x_2 \otimes (y_2 \otimes z)$?

Comment: The map $M ×N \longrightarrow M \otimes N$ is not always injective. Right?

Comment: So we may have $(m_1,n_1),(m_2,n_2) \in M \times N$ with  $(m_1,n_1) \neq (m_2,n_2)$ but  $m_1 \otimes n_1 = m_2 \otimes n_2$.

Comment: Please help me to overcome from the stage where I got stuck.

Comment: @ArnabChatterjee. Linear maps from $M\otimes N$ correspond exactly to bilinear maps from $M\times N$. This is the *universal property* of tensor products.